# RegEx search and replace on JSON file using VBScript

Tags: json, regex, replace, vbscript

I am pretty new to regex but been trying to find my way in searching and replacing a text from a JSON file. I am interested in having it done via VBScript as most of my scripts are already completed on this language.

I have a JSON filename `site.json` assuming

```json
"Source" : {
    "ConfigName" : "SiteName",
    "Name" : "ABCTest"
}
"Windows" : {
    "MachineSID" : "15371-868-9808907-15424"
}
```

I am trying to search for the `MachineSID` and replace its value once found such that it will retain everything but change to:

```json
...
"MachineSID" : "123456"
```

Then save it afterwards to the same filename `site.json`.

Comment: What you've tried so far?

Comment: By what rule would `15371-868-9808907-15424` be reduced to `123456`?

Answer (score 0):

This regex can be used to catch the MachineSID in group 1:

```
"MachineSID" *: *"([\d-]+?)"
```

https://regex101.com/r/YfXwRP/1